# Cassandra column family last access time

Tags: cassandra

Is there a way to check, when was the last time, a column family accessed to fetch or insert any record? I am newbie to cassandra, so apology if this sounds silly but could not find any answers on here or web? Please help

Answer (score 3):

No, Cassandra does not have a built-in way to do this.  Of course, you can always update a column holding a timestamp (in some other dedicated column family) every time you read from or write to the column family.

Answer (score 1):

1. One possible solution that I was advised is, using cqlsh, 'Select * from  Limit 1' and this will tell me, whether CF is empty, hence unused or if there are some rows, hence used. Silly but will work in absense of perfect solution.
2. Can check the file access time into SSTables and determine, when was the last, these files were modified.

Hope it helps.